# What is the minimum set of registers to fill for ADS-B?

Tags: ads-b, mode-s

I am researching about Automatic Dependent Surveillance-Broadcast mode of Mode S currently. On a third party document, I encountered a list of transponder registers to be filled; 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 0A, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65 as the list of registers.The source is Grappel 2007- ATC 334.

05(Airborne position), 06(Surface Position), 08(Aircraft Id), 09(Airborne velocity) registers seem to be carrying most important data for ADS-B.

Registers from 61 to 65  are called event driven registers, carrying slowly changing data. **SHALL** these registers have to be filled with correct values to serve ADS-B IN capable systems? What happens if I don' t service these event-driven registers?

Is there a definitive list of registers to fill current settled ADS-B standards?

Note: I have access to many documents, so feel free to refer some well-known ADS-B documents.

Answer (score 4):

ADS-B IN systems do require information from the 0x6X registers. These registers hold information like ADS-B protocol version, system design assurance level and position source quality indicators.

Without this information the ADS-B IN system can establish a track, but the quality will be flagged as too low to display.

For reference, get a copy of RTCA DO-260B or EUROCAE ED-102A, whichever is cheaper. They are the Minimum  Operational  Performance Standards for 1090 MHz Extended Squitter Automatic Dependent Surveillance – Broadcast  (ADS-B).

Comment: The MOPS describes several classes of ADS-B equipment, not all of which are applicable.  You may get some help in picking the right class by reading [TSO-C166b](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgTSO.nsf/0/e70544d62a001f87862576820057970f/$FILE/TSO-166b.pdf) as it includes specific FAA guidance regarding classes and functionality.

Comment: Gerry, what do you mean with "not applicable"? Perhaps you mean not applicable in the US. However, the TSO you refer to is not applicable outside the US. For all ADS-B specifications the TSO refers to DO-260B. The standard functioning of ADS-B IN, and the necessary registers are described in the MOPS, not in the TSO.

Comment: DO-260B describes a number of classes of ADS-B equipment.  The minimum data set required is dependent on the class the manufacturer desires to certificate the equipment to.  Note that Class A equipment must support both ADS-B IN and OUT.  Class B is ADS-B OUT only.  There are other classes for ground vehicles.  While the TSO only covers FAA approvals, there is an equivalent ETSO for EASA.  DO-260B and ED-102A are harmonized documents so the rules are the same. ADS-B OUT data standards depend on the chosen Class.  ADS-B IN data support can be 'universal' or limited to defined applications.

Comment: Looking back, it's not clear whether the Mehmet is discussing the design of the ADS-B link or it's installation.  For installation, information is available in [AC 20-165B](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_20-165B.pdf) for ADS-B OUT and [AC 20-172B](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC20-172B.pdf) for ADS-B OUT.

Comment: I was asking about ADS-B OUT data coverage to be exact. Could we "get away" with not updating certain ADS-B allocated registers. Would ignoring some registers anger ATC?